# Kivy closeable TabbedPanel

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I tried extracting the code for a closeable `TabbedPanel` [from github here](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/tabbed_panel_showcase.py).

It works all fine but the content of the tab is not cleared as well, just the header. **How can I remove the content of the Tab when closing it as well?**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanel, TabbedPanelHeader
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.lang import Builder


class CloseableHeader(TabbedPanelHeader):
    pass

class TestTabApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string('''
TabbedPanel:
    do_default_tab: False
    FloatLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            id: tab_1_content
            Label:
                text: 'Palim 1'
        BoxLayout:
            id: tab_2_content
            Label:
                text: 'Palim 2'
        BoxLayout:
            id: tab_3_content
            Label:
                text: 'Palim 3'


    CloseableHeader:
        text: 'tab1'
        panel: root
        content: tab_1_content.__self__
    CloseableHeader:
        text: 'tab2'
        panel: root
        content: tab_2_content.__self__
    CloseableHeader:
        text: 'tab3'
        panel: root
        content: tab_3_content.__self__


<CloseableHeader>
    color: 0,0,0,0
    disabled_color: self.color
    # variable tab_width
    text: 'tabx'
    size_hint_x: None
    width: self.texture_size[0] + 40
    BoxLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        size_hint: None, None
        size: root.size
        padding: 3
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: root.text
        BoxLayout:
            size_hint: None, 1
            orientation: 'vertical'
            width: 22
            Button:
                on_press:
                    root.panel.remove_widget(root)

''')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestTabApp().run()
```

If I close tab 2, while being on tab 2.
[image]

I would like to see tab 1, right now I will still see the content of tab2.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, in your code you just remove header. To also clear all the widgets in the content area, you have to add the following command:

```
Button:
    on_press:
        root.panel.switch_to(root.panel.tab_list[root.panel.tab_list.index(root.panel.current_tab) - 1])
        root.panel.remove_widget(root)
        root.content.clear_widgets()
```

Now the content area is cleared and another content is shown.

Comment: Unfortunately, this will only clear the widget, but I was hoping if I close tab2, tab1 becomes automatically visible.

Comment: It still will not show me the content of tab1 if I am on tab2 and close tab2. Hence I upvoted but did not accept the answer.

Comment: @PalimPalim I am stubborn... And I think i got it this time :)

Comment: Yes, you did. Sometimes it pays to be stubborn. Thanks!

Comment: @PalimPalim Note that if you add the first command (`switch_to`) after you remove the widget, an error is raised because the widget doesn't exist anymore and the list position can't be calculated. That's why i put it first.